# change IAP SKU using apktool

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, apktool, sku

Due to the age of a project we are forced to use apktool to decompile and recompile a project. The app is free to download and uses IAP to unlock main feature.

The IAP was deleted by accident from the play console and now we need to change the SKU in the app itself. We replaced all instances we found after decompiling with apktool. But after recompiling, it still uses the old SKU...

Is that simply a security feature (to protect owners from IAP hacks) or how could we achieve the SKU change?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't change that without changing the signature of the app.

Comment: It's not a security feature. You must've missed one. I assume you've verified that the recompilation was successful by decompiling the new .apk and checking the SKUs?